# HTTPRequestException: "Connection refused" when connecting to localhost API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, http

I'm facing an issue with my ASP.NET Core application where I'm getting a "Connection refused" error when trying to connect to a localhost API. The specific error is:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused. (localhost:7146)

--Edit--

The thing I want to do in the project is to add a new row to the Category table. Before adding the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` operations to `CategoryController1.cs`, my application was working as follows: I could run the application with `Ctrl+F5` and then navigate from the `Index.cshtml` page to the design page with `Ctrl+Shift+W`. After adding the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` operations, when I tried to run the application directly from `Index.cshtml`, I encountered this error:

> SignalRWebUI.Controllers.CategoryController1.Index() in CategoryController1.cs + var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7146/api/Category");" This part shows an error.

I've tried , but none of them seem to solve the issue. Below is a snippet of the code where the exception occurs:

1.CategoryController1.cs

```
public class CategoryController1 : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public CategoryController1(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7146/api/Category");
        if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        {
            var jsonData=await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var values =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultCategoryDto>>(jsonData);//Verileri çekme için 
            return View(values);
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateCategory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async  Task<IActionResult> CreateCategory(CreateCategoryDto createCategoryDto)
    {
        createCategoryDto.Status = true;
        var client= _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createCategoryDto);
        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonData,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
        var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7146/api/Category",stringContent);
        if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
 }
```

2.Index.cshtml

```
@model List<SignalRWebUI.Dtos.CategoryDtos.ResultCategoryDto>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/AdminLayoutController1/Index.cshtml";
}

<div class="content">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <h4 class="page-title">Kategori İşlemleri</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="card-title">Kategori Listesi</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-sub">
                        Kategori ile ilgili işlemleri aşağıdan gerçekleştirebilirsiniz :
                    </div>
                    <table class="table mt-3">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Kategori Adı</th>
                                <th scope="col">Durum</th>
                                <th scope="col">Sil</th>
                                <th scope="col">Güncelle</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach(var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.CategoryID</td>
                                    <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
                                    <td>@item.Status</td>
                                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger" >Sil</a> </td>
                                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success" >Günelle</a> </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href="/Category/CreateCategory/" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Yeni Kategori Girişi</a>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: And what happens if you try to open one of the used `https://localhost:7146` urls in browser?

Comment: I've encountered an issue where, upon pasting "https://localhost:7146/" into the browser, I receive an "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error. However, when I press Ctrl+F5 within the application, the page loads without any problems.

Comment: You have a post action that's trying to call itself? It's not clear what you want to do with this code.

Comment: Updated the post, can you take another look

Comment: Make sure you can get data by using Postman first.  Usually we may get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when we use the wrong port or when the webapp doesn't start.

Comment: I think you got it all wrong.  IHttpclientfactory is used in a class library when you Web Api is hosted, so you could address your methods from your web api.
The methods inside your CategoryController (that should be your web api),  needs a service.  This service has crud methods where you refer to you DbContext, for example "_dbContext.Items.ToListAsync();"
Once your class library with the Ihttpclientfactory methods are created, you inject this inside Blazor.